# jQuery Slideshow + Click to Enlarge (LightBox and ColorBox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, slideshow, colorbox

The Question:
I would like to use the slide-show I currently have in place BUT with the option of clicking the image to enlarge. Enlarge would use a lightbox (you know, all fancy pants style)

Here is the page I am working with as an example:

http://newsite.702wedding.com/valley-of-fire-weddings.aspx

The slide-show is on the right, again, I just need to be able to click the image and enlarge it. While maintaining the arrows functionality.

Any Help Would be Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Search colorbox, it is very popular, very light, very versatile. But my personal favourite is Fancybox.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do something similar and couldn't find anything already out there. So I combined [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) with [tinySlideshow](http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/12/javascript-slideshow/).

http://jsfiddle.net/AmT8x/23/

It's not the cleanest solution, but it did the job I needed it for.